# Wordpress plugin building for pdf conversion and email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm trying to write a simple plugin that converts WP Form submissions into PDF files and automatically translates them into three different languages using the Google Translate API.
My development environment is on localhost. And I've tried the code on the server as well, the issue persists.

The problem I'm facing is that the code doesn't even send email. And I've been trying to debug that with no success. If I send a test email using WordPress's wp_mail function, it doesn't seem to work as expected. The email sending functionality is a crucial part of my plugin, and I'd appreciate any assistance in identifying and resolving this issue.

Here's my current code so far:

```
    <?php
    /*
    PLUGIN DESCRIPTION HERE
    */

    // Hook into the WPForms submission process
    add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'translate_send_pdf_wpforms_process_complete', 10, 4);

    function echo_log( $what )
    {
        echo '<pre>'.print_r( $what, true ).'</pre>';
    }

    function translate_send_pdf_wpforms_process_complete($fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id) {
        
        $form_data = wpforms()->form->get($form_data['id']);
        echo_log($form_data);
        $user_submitted_data = wpforms()->entry->get($entry_id);

        // send_test_email($entry_id);

        $name_field = 'Single Line Text'; 
        $person_name = isset($user_submitted_data[$name_field]) ? $user_submitted_data[$name_field] : 'Unknown';

        error_log('person_name: ' . print_r($person_name, true));
        echo $person_name;
        echo 'hello';

        // Generate PDF for each language
        $languages = array('de', 'fr', 'es');
        $pdf_files = array();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $translated_content = translate_content($user_submitted_data, $language);
            $pdf_content = generate_pdf($translated_content);
            $pdf_files[$language] = $pdf_content;
        }
        send_pdf_email(
            $pdf_files,
            $languages,
            $person_name
        );

    }

    // Function to translate content
    function translate_content($content, $target_language) {
        $api_key = 'API KEY HERE';
        $url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $api_key;

        $data = array(
            'q' => $content,
            'source' => 'en',
            'target' => $target_language,
        );

        // Initialize cURL session
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        // Execute the translation request
        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        // Close the cURL session
        curl_close($handle);

        // Parse the translation response
        $translation_data = json_decode($response, true);

        // Check if translation was successful
        if (isset($translation_data['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'])) {
            // Extract and return the translated content
            $translated_content = $translation_data['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
            return $translated_content;
        } else {
            // Return the original content if translation failed
            return $content;
        }

        return $content;
    }

    // Function to generate PDF from content using TCPDF
    function generate_pdf($content) {
        // Include the TCPDF library if not already included
        if (!class_exists('TCPDF')) {
            require_once('/tcpdf-wrapper/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
        }

        // Create a new TCPDF instance
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        // Set document information
        $pdf->SetCreator('Name');
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Name');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Translated PDF');
        $pdf->SetSubject('Translated PDF');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('PDF, translation');

        // Set default header and footer fonts
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

        // Set margins
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

        // Set auto page breaks
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

        // Add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();

        // Set font
        $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);

        // Add content to the PDF
        $pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, $content, 0, 'L');

        // Output the PDF to a variable
        $pdf_content = $pdf->Output('', 'S');

        return $pdf_content;
    }

    function send_pdf_email($pdf_files, $languages, $person_name) {
        $to = '...@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'New Form Submission'; 
        $message = 'Please find the attached PDFs for the following languages: ' . implode(', ', $languages);

        $attachments = array();
        $current_date = date('Y-m-d');

        // Loop through PDF files and attach them
        foreach ($pdf_files as $language => $pdf_content) {
            $pdf_file_name = "New_Form_{$person_name}_{$current_date}_{$language}.pdf";
            $attachments[$pdf_file_name] = $pdf_content;
        }

        // Send the email
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, '', $attachments);
    }

    function send_test_email($person_name) {
        $to = '...@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Test Email';
        $message = "This is a test email sent from your WordPress plugin. {$person_name}";
        $result = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);

    }



    ?>
```

I tried to send a test email using WordPress's wp_mail function in my plugin code. I expected the test email to be successfully sent to the specified recipient email address, and to see the message 'Test email sent successfully.' However I am only able to receive emails through the WP Forms feature when I set the send email option in the Settings/Notifications on WP Forms. I do have the WP Mail SMTP plugin installed. The description of the WP Mail SMTP plugin is: Reconfigures the wp_mail() function to use Gmail/Mailgun/SendGrid/SMTP instead of the default mail() and creates an options page to manage the settings.

And on another note, when my plugin is active it blocks the confirmation message from being displayed.

Comment: *"If I send a test email using WordPress's wp_mail function, it doesn't seem to work"* So this question has nothing to do with PDF or Google Translate. You don't need to post 150 lines of code just to show how you send an email.

Comment: You need to configure your host to send emails. When it's localhost, that's your own development machine. Read one of ther many tutorials available online about configuring WordPress  /  SMTP  / outbound email messages. Make sure your test messages go before trying to troubleshoot the code you use to make your pdfs.

Comment: @Olivier Wrong, it has to do with those, and some line in the code is causing the problem because if I just send an email it goes through, but after getting the form data it doesn't send the email, and it also blocks the confirmation message. Learn how to read or skim through the code.